# Count values only if they're running on or after the week which is used to group the values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been struggling with this query for a bit so I'd appreciate some help.

I'm currently attempting to show a running sum of suppliers who had classes running on or past a specific date, the sum should be a running sum and show WoW growth.

eg. if a supplier had a classes running from w/c 16/01 until w/c 06/02 they should be counted in the rows for those weeks but not before w/c 16/01 or after w/c 06/02.

I am not sure how to express with SQL the above, I have access to the dates of all sessions running for specific suppliers. Below is the code I currently have:

```
1. with c as (select 
2. date_trunc('week', ms.created_at)::DATE "created_at",
3. SUM(count(distinct ms.id)) over (order by date_trunc('week', ms.created_at)::DATE) "supplier_count"
4. from marketplace_supplier ms
5. join marketplace_activity ma on ma.supplier_id = ms.id 
6. join (select 
7. ma.id "activity_id",
8. count(distinct s.id) filter (where s.is_deleted = false // further condition here to specify 9. which sessions to count) "bookable_sessions",
10. min(s.date) "first_session",
11. max(s.date) "last_session"
12. from marketplace_supplier ms
13. join marketplace_activity ma on ma.supplier_id = ms.id 
14. join marketplace_activitysession s on s.activity_id = ma.id
15. group by 
16. ma.id) s on s.activity_id = ma.id 
17. where ma.booking_type = 'instant' and ms.is_deleted = FALSE and s.bookable_sessions > 0 and 
18. ma.status = 'PUBLISHED' 
19. group by 
20. date_trunc('week',ms.created_at)::DATE
21. order by 
22. date_trunc('week',ms.created_at)::DATE desc)
23. select 
24. c.created_at,
25. sum(c.supplier_count) "weekly_running_sum",
26. (sum(c.supplier_count) - lag(sum(c.supplier_count)) 
27. over (order by c.created_at))::numeric / lag(sum(c.supplier_count)) over (order by c.created_at)::numeric "%_growth"
28. from  c 
29. group by c.created_at 
30. order by c.created_at desc
```

My current issue is in line 8 in the CTE, I'm not sure how to specify which sessions to count, currently usign DBeaver w/ a PostgreSQL DB.

[This is the current output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJV45.png)
Kind regards,
C

Comment: without create tables and data as text we can't help you

Comment: Too much MBA (?) jargon for a forum about programming.